# Como ocultar a scrollbar ao tirar o mouse e torna-la visível ao colocar o mouse?

Tags: css

Bem galera, eu fiz uma side-nav com alguns conteúdos e gostaria de deixar uma barra de rolagem visível quando o mouse estiver em cima, porém, também gostaria de oculta-la quando o mouse estiver fora dessa side-nav.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie um arquivo css com uma classe com o nome da sua `side-nav`, ou caso seja uma classe, este código já está correto.

```
.side-nav{
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.side-nav:hover{
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```